# How to clone github repository in aptana studio 3?

Tags: git, github, clone, aptana

I have a repo on github for django code.
How can I clone it locally on aptana studio 3?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out myself. It looks like it is very simple

1. You can go to File->Import->Git -> Git Repository as new project
   This can be used to clone a remote project locally
2. If you get an error of exec: wish3 or something simply install 
   **sudo apt-get install python-tk**